# Cant import firebase_database.dart Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, dependencies

im trying to add a dependence in my pubspec.yaml but the
`import 'package:firebase_database/firebase_database.dart'` is taged with `"Target of URI doesn't exist: 'package:firebase_database/firebase_database.dart'"`

i cheked my pubspec.yaml and i've all dependences, but it still taged like error

```
dependencies:
  cloud_firestore: ^3.1.5
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  firebase_database: ^2.0.2
  firebase_auth: ^1.0.4
  firebase_core: ^0.4.0

  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
    
  fluttertoast: ^8.0.8
  font_awesome_flutter: ^9.0.0
  google_sign_in: ^5.0.3
  provider: ^5.0.0

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `flutter clean && flutter pub get`.
Somtimes the package does not get included.